# Twitter OAuth Library - Login twice?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm getting started with the OAuth library provided by Abraham Williams (many thanks Abraham) but I'm running into a curious situation where:

1. I go to the index.php page, click on the "Sign in with Twitter" button
2. Redirect to callback.php
3. Callback detects mismatch between requested OAuth token and session OAuth token
4. Redirects back to connect
5. Login again through twitter
6. Finally hit the index.php with the OAuth Token and OAuth Token Secret

Is this normal, having to login to Twitter twice with Twitter OAuth?

Comment: Doesn't sound normal. Perhaps a link to this OAuth library would be helpful.

Comment: As requested,thanks PhpMyCoder https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/

Comment: The first check in the callback.php to see whether or not the session OAuth token matches the one sent by twitter (vis-a-vis $_REQUEST) seems to fail after the initial login, after a repeat login (it seems for the duration of the session) it works, but when I close the browser I have to login twice again...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because of you are trying to access using non www url and you might be mentioned in www callback url in twitter application settings or vice versa.

I had faced the same issue and I finally realized that I was trying to login using non-www url.

I have resolved the issue by using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter gives you temporary tokens during the OAuth authentication process (after request_tokens). You have to get rid of them after access_tokens. I think that your token mismatch may be here because when you authorize an application for the second time (or more), Twitter gives you the tokens he gave you the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the redirect to connect. Make sure that this redirects to the script processing the connect and not just the login page.